# FME : How can I use multiple Workspacerunners in one Workspace?

Tags: fme-form, workspace, transformer

I created two Workspaces, the first one does a clipping process and the second has to run it. It contains a "Creator" and 4 Workspace-runners. 
I have 4 different Inputs and outputs paths, how can I launch my main workspace and only specify in each workspacerunner the INPUTS and the OUTPUTS?

Thanks ![image]

---

I'm sorry I wasn't very explicit. What you said describes what I wanted to do. I have a Dataset that I use each time "communal areas" and 4 others "pipelines" that I change each time. What I want is that I don't have to change my INPUTS/OUTPUTS directories each time. This is why I used Workspace-runners but it didn't work. I think I have a problem in my main workbench because I had this Error Message :

---

```
2013-09-13 17:04:31|   0.4|  0.0|INFORM|WorkspaceRunner_2: Running FME Workspace W:\LAB\...decoupage_canalisations.fmw with command line:
2013-09-13 17:04:31|   0.4|  0.0|INFORM|WorkspaceRunner_2: {C:/Program Files/FME_2013/fme} W:/LAB/.../Decoupage_cana_dep/decoupage_canalisations.fmw --SourceDataset_SHAPE {W:\LAB\...\INPUTS\DIFF_MPC\*.shp} --SourceDataset_SHAPE_3 {W:\LAB\..._REGION\*.shp} --DestDataset_SHAPE {W:\LAB\...OUTPUTS\DIFF_MPC} --LOG_FILE {W:\LAB\...\LOGS\DIFF_MPC} 2>@1
2013-09-13 17:04:35|   0.4|  0.0|WARN  |WorkspaceRunner_2: Failed to run workspace W:/LAB.../decoupage_canalisations.fmw -- Trace was:

                 FME 2013 SP2 (20130605 - Build 13499 - WIN32)
                  FME Desktop Professional Edition (floating)
                               Permanent License.
                        Machine host name is: L50026151
                Copyright (c) 1994 - 2013 by Safe Software Inc.
                               Safe Software Inc.


Unable to open log file `W:\LAB\...\LOGS\DIFF_MPC'
Program Terminating
```

---

Translation FAILED.
I Put another screenshot of the main workbench.! 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to setup some parameters in the main workspace see http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist72/

Comment: I am not working with FME 2011 but with FME Desktop 2013. 
It is the first time that I use multiple Workspace-runners.

Comment: its more about the methodology than the version of FME, FME updates transformers but the process should be the same.

Comment: Do you know how to use multiple workspace-runners that launch the same workbench ? It worked when used only one. Maybe I should put a creator for each workspace-runne ?

Comment: Can you please write out what you are trying to do in simple terms? I think that you are overthinking it. I'm sure you can do what you want to do with one workspace.

Perhaps upload your workspace and sample data, if you are really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to run the 2nd workspace but with four different datasets? Because what you have seems to be OK; albeit that you've only connected the Successful port, so that any failed workspaces will prevent the others from processing.

> how can I launch my main workspace and only specify in each
>   workspacerunner the INPUTS and the OUTPUTS?

The screenshot you have seems to show exactly that. You can just open the parameters dialog for each and specify the input and output dataset in there.

If this is failing to work, can you explain how exactly it is failing?

Incidentally, if there are various files to be processed, and you don't know what they are, then perhaps replace the Creator with a Directory and File Pathnames Reader. That will read a list of files in a folder that you could then pass to the WorkspaceRunner. Then you would only need one of them.